# Jupyter + rpy2 outputs to command prompt instead of notebook cell

Tags: python, r, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, rpy2

#### Issue description

Whenever loading rpy2 in a Jupyter notebook, R code executed with a `%%R`cell magic gets printed in the command prompt instead of the notebook cell. Plots show up properly in the notebook though.

[image]

I also noticed that the `%R` inline magic works properly, with code printed in the cell as expected.

#### Installation steps

1. Python 2.7.11 :: Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)
2. notebook 4.1.0 installed via pip
3. R 3.3.1 (x64) located in Program Files
4. [rpy2-2.7.8-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rpy2) installed via pip
5. PATH:

   - `R_USER = C:\Users\myusername`
   - `R_HOME = C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1`
   - Added `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\bin\i386`

Comment: I don't know, seems to work fine for me on the mac. Can you show the exact commands you're using to activate the rmagic? Otherwise, might be a windows thing.

Comment: I call `%load_ext rpy2.ipython` and then add `%%R` at the top of the cell.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did and it works for me. You could try submitting a bug report on rpy2's bitbucket site

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no...

Comment: For reference, the bug report page is here: https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/506/rpy2-cell-magic-on-jupyter-notebook

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [RWinOut](https://github.com/vitorcurtis/RWinOut) Jupyter extension. The following installation instructions are taken from the GitHub page:

You can run the following `curl` command from a Jupyter notebook cell to download the file to your working directory. You can also download it manually and put it there yourself.

```
!curl -O "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vitorcurtis/RWinOut/master/RWinOut.py"
```

Once it's in your working directory, you can replace `%load_ext rpy2.ipython` at the top of your script with `%load_ext RWinOut`. Then you should be able to see the output of cells containing the `%%R` magic as normal.

This isn't a complete solution, but it's a workaround that might achieve the same effect. I'm not sure if this breaks some functionality, but it seems to work fine for me.

Tested with:

- Windows 10 v.1809 Build 17763.503
- Python 3.7.2
- R 3.6.0
- rpy2 2.9.5

One other option is to use the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) and launch your Jupyter notebook from there. This might not be desirable if you have to reinstall a lot of R and Python packages into a different environment, but will make it so the output will print correctly without requiring this hacky workaround.

Comment: Running Linux in Windows might be long term solution. The dev version of rpy2 (future rpy2-3.1.0) has tentative initialization code for Windows but to my knowledge it was not tested by anyone.